# Dell Monitor U2713HM will not display at 2560x1440 resolution on Windows 10

Tags: display, resolution

I have a Dell display monitor U2713HM and recently upgraded my Dell XPS desktop from Windows 7 to Windows 10. Under Windows 7 the monitor runs fine at 2560 * 1440 resolution and I can run the Display manager to change the screen layout without any problems. Under Windows 10 the resolution (default is 1024 * 768) and only the generic Windows driver is shown. The display manager will not run under Windows 10.

I checked the Dell website and they basically offer no resolution (a dedicated driver for Windows 10 is not forthcoming). I followed the steps they advised to check (Control Panel - Display Resolution - and then I find there is no option to set the monitor to its max resolution).  I downloaded the driver from the Dell website for Windows 7 / 8 and installed it under Windows 10.  Then tried to run this program.  It recognises the display, but I cannot select any of the options presented.  So I am stuck. Gone back to Windows 7.

Anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: post the correct name of your Dell XPS desktop PC so that we can see which hardware you have.

Answer (score 3):

The resolutions available tend to be dictated by your graphics driver not the drivers for your display if they have any particular special functions.

First you need to identify your Graphics Card (If any, you could be using integrated graphics) by visiting Device Manager (Right-Click the start button, Left-Click Device Manager) and then expanding Display Adapters.

Depending on the information there, you should be able to search for a Windows 10 driver for your graphics adapter. Install it and display settings should be able to have the full resolution set.

If you want a specific link to the driver you need, reply in a comment with the Display Adapter listed in Device Manager.

Comment: The specific difference between this and what's already been tried: You can get newer graphics drivers from the company making the graphics chip (usually Intel, AMD, or nVidia) rather than the computer manufacturer (Dell in this example).  You should be able to obtain and test new drivers in Windows 7, before going to the effort of repeating the upgrade.

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention this key detail. Thanks. Although it sounds like he is checking for monitor drivers over display adapter drivers.

Comment: Good point regarding the graphics cards.  I have two GEForce 8800 cards in the system each with 4GB of memory.  The driver version is 311.06.  I will check for an updated driver.   Luckily I made an ISO image of Windows 10, so re- installing is not that bad.

Comment: More Information, I downloaded an updated diver for the graphics card and installed the new driver.  Works a charm on Windows 7.  Decided to reinstall Windows 10.  The same problem.  I found in the Advanced Display Settings details an error message that the device DISPLAY\DEFAULTMONITOR\... could not be migrated.   Checking the error log (Kernel PnP for Generic Device Driver gave error with event id 441.  Checking the status of the NVIDIA Control Panel showed that the program is disabled.  I think I may need to contact Microsoft to find out what is going on.  Ah well back to Windows 7.

Comment: The problem there is likely the age of the cards. They pretty ancient at this point and on an older DX version, compatibility will likely be EOL with 7. If you felt like a cheap upgrade the two 8800s could be replaced with one low power modern card and give the same performance with less heat and energy wasted.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the same screen and the problem is that the Dell Display Manager program (DDM) has not been ported to Windows 10.  No mention by Microsoft in its pre update checks. Windows 10 is not listed as compatible for DDM/U2713H monitor on Dell site.

I could alter the display to 2560x1440 manually using a generic driver, but the the Dell Display Manager does much more, notable dividing the screen into predefined windows and layouts and auto/manually switching between RGB and sRGB depending on the program being used.

I was not prepared to give up all that functionality - so back to Windows 8.1 - fortunately, the roll back works well.

Another snafu.

**Updating my earlier comment...**

I contacted the writers of Dell Display Manager (support@entechtaiwan.com), who promptly advised me that DDM had been converted to Windows 10 quite some time ago and gave me this link (//www.delldisplaymanager.com/ddmsetup.exe) for it.

The Dell web site and Dell support personnel who both currently state that there is no DDM for Windows 10 for the U2713H, as at this date, are simply wrong.

After last months after retreat from Windows 10, this second upgrade to Windows 10 has everything working just fine. DDM is great and has already auto-updated and, unlike a month ago, the Dell U2713H screen is recognised as such by Windows 10.

Only Windows 10 downside encountered so far, is the size of the tray icons - which quite a number of people have commented on elsewhere - only resize option is to make them even smaller or increase absolutely everything or introduce a 3rd party start menu with an option to increase them about 20%. Hopefully that will change.

As an aside, the retreat from Windows 10 also stopped Macrium Reflect from running - unless the PC had very recently been restarted. Something was blocking it after, say 10 minutes. That downgrade SNAFU has disappeared with the permanent upgrade to Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my even older Geforce GT320M. Eventually I forced a custom resolution and this worked perfectly. Just be careful to ensure you do know the actual maximum native resolution.

NVidia Control Panel > Display > Change resolution > Customize

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is the only solution that worked for me. The 'DDM' program told me I don't have a dell monitor attached.

Comment: I only see `3D Settings` but not `display` and `video`

Answer (score 0):

I was also having an issue. Thought it was Windows 10 but it was actually an issue with the cable I was using. Apparently the U2713HM won't work with an HDMI or single channel DVI cable. Only dual channel DVI or DisplayPort. I'm using an Alienware 13 with a Alienware Graphics accelerator with a Titan X attached so it was obviously not older hardware. Really shocking that the Dell display wouldn't accept HDMI as the newer standards, e.g. 1.4, should easily drive 2560X1440. Ordered a Displayport cable today. If I don't post back it worked.

Comment: Please refer to [how to write a good answer ?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: It does work with an HDMI cable for me, just need to set it up with custom resolution & refresh rate